# PyInstaller: how to create multiple programs in one folder?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm developing a Python package and have about 10 demo Python scripts that show its capabilities.

I want to distribute the demo scripts with PyInstaller: create 10 exe files and put them in one folder with all libraries they depend on.

Cannot you tell me, how can it be done?

Comment: Umm, create them at different folders then copy+paste to the same folder?

Comment: I was looking for the same question.  The crux is does each program have to be a standalone 7Mb+ exe or can you have something like a dll?

Answer (score 2):

This feature is present in pyinstaller, but unfortunately it is [broken in since version 3.0](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/spec-files.html#multipackage-bundles)

This [bug report](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1527) states it will not be included in the 3.4 release either.

Comment: As of Apr 9, 2020, [a fix has been merged](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/4303). If you got here like I did, [this link will take you to the updated documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/spec-files.html#multipackage-bundles) for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org) can do this.  I found it a little harder to use than pyinstaller but for this application is probably right.

This has been answered in another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321700/15-python-scripts-into-one-executable) and I suggest going there for more details.