# Create exe files from .py

Tags: python, module, exe

I have a program with python and it has 3 modules .py.

what should i do to create exe format of this program?

i try this with pyinstaller but thats create exe for my main .py and other .py

modules not contains in it!

Comment: You should use py2exe. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321700/15-python-scripts-into-one-executable

Comment: @DecaK  Deceased unless you use Python 2

Comment: You could use Pyinstaller or cx_Freeze for  a Python 3 project http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Check this library: https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix

Answer (score 0):

Install pyinstaller:
Go to command prompt and type `pip install pyinstaller`.

Create .exe:
If you want to create a .exe from a .py you need to open your command prompt under the correct directory of the file and type:

```
pyinstaller —-onefile filename  // e.g hello.py as the filename
```

If it has any basic graphics, type the following in command prompt

```
pyinstaller —-onefile -w then your file name
```

This should all work.

If it does not I recommend that you watch this [video](https://youtu.be/UZX5kH72Yx4).